# Tool/s to monitor a MongoDB Cluster

Tags: mongodb

What tool/s do you recommend using to monitor a MongoDB cluster with sharding and replica set enabled? I prefer a tool which can report on MongoDB cluster internals and not just generic stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MMS](http://mms.10gen.com) is good and there is a list of others [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Monitoring+and+Diagnostics).

Answer (score 1):

Mongostat is your friend here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongostat